# Error Merging fields from Dynamics CRM workflow

Tags: dynamics-crm, docusignapi

I am trying to merge fields using Docusign for Dynamics. I have signed up for Sandbox Docusign and using with dynamics 365 CRM.

When I try to write a workflow to merge field using template , I receive following error. In docusign Template is perfect . Any help appreciated.

```
[DocuSignIntegration: DocuSign.DSIntegrationActivity.GetSignatures]
[DocuSignIntegration: DocuSign.DSIntegrationActivity.GetSignatures]

Calling endpoint https://partner.docusign.net/partners/msdynamics/api/GetSignatures
POST data: t=L%2BUL0dVaJKrxG7jPjGXtUacp4FfMOWprKbw6ML9qcvvUX76oVsfPu3hJ0sk3wbfc7SK6nQXcw44eGuum1P%2Fea2wlZxitPj%2Bas%2B52vVlmOq4%3D&baseUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fdemo.docusign.net&accountId=6b76af6b-6663-4b1b-aea4-6fedb0b159bf&uid=c20189f4-73d3-4298-8065-36e04a089458&refreshToken=AQABAAAAAAAm-06blBE1TpVMil8KPQ41Qy0jKUb0TMSdpFJKrCmxKKQWM9NCQTqtV3LKgZLnb47f-NnmSMgL2ssfXvlpw_9jcKLy7n_c-AmQhLjKXynoUgkUYt3-5ZeMaggxr7yT7Td1CeBVYQ4mV68t8TT-Eb5kbwcglNW-u5UuStp1KEKrVrePjq__n3PnTq9tMCBoUxCiIobg4Xj-aSSNeoH9UappzpFqhHjs8a1tv7JyJaDxJfEED8R2i_bXb6D54gPqDiZDhKBfiIBg29JgwReIIZeqWQytBnuQ-Mlitlmvw5LSHVgHA6CS6OFpvT36cIpjgejbakshREilAMbSt8U2kpOZ1MV9O89H7qkSJs_XGh02uPHptjiGPcdAkaKIL39HPNoTLz24EKXFmPB9i8X596LKBu7pil6D4QfL5nPSnoFWVDCvQE7Ot0wm9O6xM1ku6r9z2pd5XrcRLYwDZZ-tQQkxdwxIimh74ipC-eeslVJN1APC2WlC1rXROD4Z3TBBS3pMZcTS8VeCgQMn4TwF9FerJjSr-rS1yBJcftPGcbqqL9Hn9NDYJmc8Id0fV_d4H9kq86SBKq11XlXeZ0r8iSTHhTV2vtheNSV1QOvFPC_PWnk7u_rXjNu2ZCipgHVaLEgU3jfnXVUHnt0Qg7wwNqxPB8fVoR4DGxiwDx-myVdhUjVKfWMzUjwNt8vy3aqh9n7dsAnHszm8x_stv2p4MP1R9YPyqW4x3NsBnHASa6iST7ejSx155voSCWjNIIi4XnSUtrRHAydlZLhVZSM4ElwWqTYkf5gHNtArAyFlIv1wlQUWf_-rrAb2Hth4r64x1g4Cvjw4VYqpcamX-LGHklwYIAA&crmHost=s34.crm.dynamics.com&v=6.2.0.13&envelopeId=25a4f2db-c8af-483b-80b8-b9caf4ca0ff7&entityLogicalName=opportunity&entityId=628cf01a-aed1-e411-80ef-c4346bac7be8&oneclicksend=True&oneclickoption=Tag&templateId=019b6c8a-3faa-4a65-a256-97382dfa1554
Deserializing json response: {"Error":"Unknown","ErrorDescription":"The Envelope is not Complete. A Complete Envelope Requires Documents, Recipients, Tabs, and a Subject Line. Error querying documents for Envelope ID = 25a4f2db-c8af-483b-80b8-b9caf4ca0ff7 (ENVELOPE_IS_INCOMPLETE)"}



Error Message:

Unhandled exception: 
Exception type: Microsoft.Crm.CrmException
Message: An unexpected error occurred from ISV code. (ErrorType = ClientError) Unexpected exception from plug-in (Execute):  DocuSign.DSIntegrationActivity.GetSignatures: System.Exception: Unable to deserialize the returned JSON.

Endpoint:  GetSignatures.
Params:  t=L%2BUL0dVaJKrxG7jPjGXtUacp4FfMOWprKbw6ML9qcvvUX76oVsfPu3hJ0sk3wbfc7SK6nQXcw44eGuum1P%2Fea2wlZxitPj%2Bas%2B52vVlmOq4%3D&baseUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fdemo.docusign.net&accountId=6b76af6b-6663-4b1b-aea4-6fedb0b159bf&uid=c20189f4-73d3-4298-8065-36e04a089458&refreshToken=AQABAAAAAAAm-06blBE1TpVMil8KPQ41Qy0jKUb0TMSdpFJKrCmxKKQWM9NCQTqtV3LKgZLnb47f-NnmSMgL2ssfXvlpw_9jcKLy7n_c-AmQhLjKXynoUgkUYt3-5ZeMaggxr7yT7Td1CeBVYQ4mV68t8TT-Eb5kbwcglNW-u5UuStp1KEKrVrePjq__n3PnTq9tMCBoUxCiIobg4Xj-aSSNeoH9UappzpFqhHjs8a1tv7JyJaDxJfEED8R2i_bXb6D54gPqDiZDhKBfiIBg29JgwReIIZeqWQytBnuQ-Mlitlmvw5LSHVgHA6CS6OFpvT36cIpjgejbakshREilAMbSt8U2kpOZ1MV9O89H7qkSJs_XGh02uPHptjiGPcdAkaKIL39HPNoTLz24EKXFmPB9i8X596LKBu7pil6D4QfL5nPSnoFWVDCvQE7Ot0wm9O6xM1ku6r9z2pd5XrcRLYwDZZ-tQQkxdwxIimh74ipC-eeslVJN1APC2WlC1rXROD4Z3TBBS3pMZcTS8VeCgQMn4TwF9FerJjSr-rS1yBJcftPGcbqqL9Hn9NDYJmc8Id0fV_d4H9kq86SBKq11XlXeZ0r8iSTHhTV2vtheNSV1QOvFPC_PWnk7u_rXjNu2ZCipgHVaLEgU3jfnXVUHnt0Qg7wwNqxPB8fVoR4DGxiwDx-myVdhUjVKfWMzUjwNt8vy3aqh9n7dsAnHszm8x_stv2p4MP1R9YPyqW4x3NsBnHASa6iST7ejSx155voSCWjNIIi4XnSUtrRHAydlZLhVZSM4ElwWqTYkf5gHNtArAyFlIv1wlQUWf_-rrAb2Hth4r64x1g4Cvjw4VYqpcamX-LGHklwYIAA&crmHost=s34.crm.dynamics.com&v=6.2.0.13&envelopeId=25a4f2db-c8af-483b-80b8-b9caf4ca0ff7&entityLogicalName=opportunity&entityId=628cf01a-aed1-e411-80ef-c4346bac7be8&oneclicksend=True&oneclickoption=Tag&templateId=019b6c8a-3faa-4a65-a256-97382dfa1554
Error Description: The Envelope is not Complete. A Complete Envelope Requires Documents, Recipients, Tabs, and a Subject Line. Error querying documents for Envelope ID = 25a4f2db-c8af-483b-80b8-b9caf4ca0ff7 (ENVELOPE_IS_INCOMPLETE) (Unknown)
Server Response: {"Error":"Unknown","ErrorDescription":"The Envelope is not Complete. A Complete Envelope Requires Documents, Recipients, Tabs, and a Subject Line. Error querying documents for Envelope ID = 25a4f2db-c8af-483b-80b8-b9caf4ca0ff7 (ENVELOPE_IS_INCOMPLETE)"}
   at Microsoft.Crm.Sandbox.SandboxCodeUnit.ProcessException(Exception originalException, IExecutionContext context, SandboxClient client, SandboxCallTracker callTracker, Boolean isSafeToRetry, DateTime performanceExecutionStartTime, SandboxTracker tracker, Guid parentExecutionId, CrmException& crmException, String& assemblyContents)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Sandbox.SandboxCodeUnit.<>c__DisplayClass24_0.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.PowerApps.CoreFramework.ActivityLoggerExtensions.Execute(ILogger logger, EventId eventId, ActivityType activityType, Action action, IEnumerable`1 additionalCustomProperties)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Telemetry.XrmTelemetryExtensions.Execute(ILogger logger, XrmTelemetryActivityType activityType, Action action)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.RemotePlugin.CrmProvider.RemotePlugin.CDSExecute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Workflow.Services.ProxyCustomActivity.Execute(CodeActivityContext executionContext)
-- End stack trace --
```

[image]

Comment: from the error description seems to be related to missing attributes

Comment: Would you please update your post with the envelope definition you used for this request?

Comment: I have updated post with defination of workflow

Answer (score 3):

usually this fails for these reasons:
1. No documents are attached, but if you used the template, then this doesn't applied
2. No recipients are provided. If you add a recipient, and the recipient role is incorrect (it's case sensitive), it will be added as a new recipient, but it might not be the required recipient the template specifies. Double check that you have the role name correct. 
3. A good way to verify what is missing, is to copy the envelope ID created in the workflow, then open a new window and login to your docusign account. Look for the envelope using this ID, and you'll see it's in a draft state. You can spot check if it does have the required recipients.

Comment: I tried using envelop ID but its says unable to access envelop